# Split rangy range crossing multiple nodes into multiple ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, rangy

How do I split a range into multiple [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) ranges cross over multiple nodes?

E.g. I have a range denoted with the `{` and `}` (the tokens are not actually in the content):

```
<p>
    I {like eggs.
</p>
<p>
    Yes I} do!
</p>
```

And I want to split the one range into 2, each in its own node, e.g:

```
<p>
    I {like eggs.
}</p>
<p>{
    Yes I} do!
</p>
```

Comment: Do you want each range to exist only within a single text node? E.g. what should happen for `<p>I {really <b>really</b> like} eggs</p>`?

Comment: @TimDown I just need them not to start in one node, and end in another. If the range completely encapsulates (like your example) any nodes, then it should be left as is.

Comment: Yup, an answer to this one would be handy for me as well. No MSIE quirks required.